# SQL Query Question ROW_CONCAT

Tags: sql

I have been stuck on this problem for quite awhile... I hope someone out there can give me a hand.

The following table is in my database:

```
Product_ID Color   Type
1          Red     Leather
1          Silver  Metal
1          Blue    Leather
2          Orange  Metal
2          Purple  Metal
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
Product_ID Type    Color
1          Leather Red, Blue
1          Metal   Silver
2          Metal   Orange, Purple
```

I know it has to do with some kind of double group by and a group_concat.... have been looking at this for an hour without figuring it out.  Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: For what database?  GROUP_CONCAT is supported by MySQL and SQLite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Product_ID, Type, GROUP_CONCAT(Color)
FROM Products
GROUP BY Product_ID, Type
```

You didn't mention which database you are using - but I'm assuming MySQL since you mention GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: +1, @DaveC remember that GROUP BY combines all rows with the same values in the columns listed in the GROUP BY.  The aggregate function GROUP_CONCAT() takes the different values from all rows that need to be combined and makes a single value.  The single value is then returned.  So in this example, you get a single result set row for each unique combination of Product_ID and Type.  Then, for each of those rows, the Color values are concatenated together by GROUP_CONCAT().